# croatian language text is not appearing on browser

Tags: php

I have written some croatian language in my page.But when i m seeing result some unsupported text is not coming on browser.This is replacing "?" there.what i have to do ?

Comment: Is the information loaded from the database?

Comment: No it is coming directly.Hardcoded text

Comment: Needs *much much* more detail. Where does the data come from, what character set(s) are you using, what character set(s) is the browser detecting, what encoding the  source files are in....

Comment: This is hardcoded text in php designing.I m using    < meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> in top. Like when i m writing string " vaše " this is showing " va?e ".What about encoding.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [UTF-8 character encoding](http://malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2007/03/12/unicode-utf8-php-mysql/).

You should also convert your HTML files to UTF-8 character set (without BOM). You can do this using Notepad++ for example.

I have tested the following code and it is working:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        vaše
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add encoding to your page, depending on what encoding you used to create your page, you need to add the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Or it's HTML5 equivalant

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```